# VS 2012: Change browser title of report

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to create reports in a Report Server Project (with queries from SQL Server).

When I deploy a report to the server, the title in the browser tab looks something like [this](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160208/62ic5j5y.jpg).

Is it possible to remove the " - Berichts-Viewer" (ReportViewer) and the hyperlink right after the name of the report?

I believe that it has something to do with how reports are rendered in HTML but I haven't been able to find a self-evident way to configure it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Auto-Generate Web Part Title - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326214.aspx

Comment: I think you need to use reportviewer control to show the report and then from there you  an assign whatever title.